# Entities and dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have a service like this and one Response entity:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
   private readonly IService1 _service1;
   private readonly IService2 _service2;

   public MyService(IService1 service1, IService2 service2)
   {
      _service1 = service1;
      _service2 = service2;
   }

   public Response method1()
   {
      //DO SOMETHING
      return new Response() { ... };
   }

   public Response method2()
   {
      //DO SOMETHING
      return new Response() { ... };
   }
}

//Entities folder
public class Response
{
   public bool Success { get; set; }
   public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Someone is trying to convince me that Response entity should be injected like this:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
   private readonly IService1 _service1;
   private readonly IService2 _service2;
   private readonly IResponse _response;

   public MyService(IService1 service1, IService2 service2, IResponse response)
   {
      _service1 = service1;
      _service2 = service2;
      _response = response;
   }

   public Response method1()
   {
      //DO SOMETHING
      return _response() { ... };
   }

   public Response method2()
   {
      //DO SOMETHING
      return _response() { ... };
   }
}

public class Response : IResponse
{
   public bool Success { get; set; }
   public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

I am sure that first solution is the correct one, but I'd like to be sure about it. Can anyone give me an opinion and a reason? Thanks

Comment: It depends on whether or not you need to unit test it. In general newing anything up in a class could be considered bad practice if your goal is to have complete coverage with unit tests. I would go with the second example in that case because response can be mocked. It really depends on what you need to do and what your goal of unit testing will be.

Comment: I agree with the second one, the first one is not DI at all for the response object. The second one allows you to mock or inject different functionality. The only reason to use the first one is that if you would never get any other kind of response, or you don't need to use DI for that object.

Comment: I don't understand why you would do this. At this level, you would be unit testing that your code gives you a proper `Response` based on your injected dependencies, namely `IService1` and `IService2` in your example. If you inject your `IResponse` object you aren't really testing your code at that point, you are testing if your mocking framework can inject the right object. However, making your return type `IResponse` instead of `Response` is something that I would do, especially if you need to mock out some of its behavior for testing.

Comment: Actually, I could see injecting it if somehow methods on `Response` are used in the calculation of the response. However, if it really is just as you provided in your example, I personally think it is overkill and I am a DI/Unit Testing fanatic.

Comment: How does that even compile?